# Strange pandoc behavior when referencing figures and converting LaTeX to Word

Tags: cross-referencing, pandoc, msword, latex-to-word

I am working on a scientific paper (my field is in biomedical engineering/imaging) and unfortunately everybody I work with insists on using Word for everything. I can't stand Word with its poor formatting, and it pales in comparison to cross-referencing figures and bibliographies. Anyway, I'm trying to use pandoc to convert my paper from LaTeX to Word as follows:

```
pandoc -s paper.tex --bibliography=mybib.bib --csl=cite.csl --filter pandoc-crossref -o paper.docx
```

I am using `pandoc-crossref` to perform the referencing. I also have a supplementary section where I have some supplementary figures that I renumber. Here is a MWE of what my .tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
}
\begin{document}
  Figure~\ref{fig:1}, Figure~\ref{fig:2} and Figure~\ref{fig:s1}.
  \begin{figure}
    Figure 1
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    Figure 2
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{figure}
  \beginsupplement
  \begin{figure}
    Figure S1
    \label{fig:s1}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I open the docx file, I see something strange:

```
Figure [fig:1], Figure [fig:2], and Figure 2
```

So for some reason, it only starts to number them after the supplement, but everything else before that doesn't get numbered. Does anyone know why this could be the case?

Thank you!

Comment: As an advice from another newbie; look through `pandoc` tutorial and documentation about this module (or filter). Answer might be there. Also note that `pandoc` from the beginning states that it cant support full conversion of documents from `.tex` format (abbreviations and such). I have actually moved to use python and perl scripts to get as sufficient conversion as possible. I always give my work as `.pdf` from `.tex` and **simplified** word "handout."

Comment: Your example is missing `\caption` commands, so it doesn't output correct figure numbers even with `pdflatex`. When I've added `\captions`, I was able convert your file correctly with TeX4ht.  Note that you need to use converter that uses LaTeX itself in the conversion process to support custom commands and all LaTeX packages. Try `make4ht -f odt filename.tex`. It doesn't produce DOCX, but ODT file, which can be opened in Word.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!

@michal.h21 Sorry my document has captions too, I just didn't include them when I wrote up this MWE. Anyway, I have tex4ht installed on my system (MacOS Catalina with TeXLive) but not make4ht. It seems tex4ht requires dvi files which I don't output. Any thoughts on how to install make4ht? Documentation says TeXLive should come with it but I don't see it

Comment: The DVI files are produced directly by `make4ht`, so you don't have to worry about that. It is strange that your TL doesn't come with `make4ht`, it is part of it for quite a long time. Do you use the full install? Have you installed it from official pages or using your package manager?

Comment: I installed it a few years ago from my package manager. I went to your GitHub and tried installing from your source. Running `make` gave errors because I lacked a font. Ran `make install` anyway which seemed to work, but then running `make4ht` on my tex file gave `module 'luaxml-domobject' not found:
 no field package.preload['luaxml-domobject']
 [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
 [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'`

Comment: @Stimulus it would be best to update your TeX distro. It seems also the LuaXML package is missing.